# Show different images on different viewport widths

Tags: fancybox-3

Is this possible? srcset does not work, so I thought about using background-images in combination with media queries. Good idea? How could this be done?

I found this code, but it only shows the url of the img and not the picture itself...somebody can help making the picture showing up? Thx!

```
$(document).on('beforeLoad.fb', function( e, instance, current ) {
current.type = 'html';
current.content = '<div class="fancybox-image" style="background-image:url(' + current.src + '); background-size: cover; background-position:50% 50%;background-repeat:no-repeat;height:100%;width:100%;" /></div>';
```

});

Comment: Why do you think that "srcset does not work"? The problem is that it is hard to debug that property, because browsers decide what source to load based on various parameters (network speed, etc) and that can lead to unexpected results (for example, browser would still display cached image when you resize window)

Comment: Hi Janis, thx for your comment. srcset does not work for me...I tried it according to your documentation and examples (which also don't work anymore). And unexpected results are not the thing I'm looking for ;-) However, do you think it is possible with background-images...in order to get some control what image is showed at certain viewport widths?

Comment: Well, for example, you could use `beforeLoad` callback to change image src depending on your conditions. FYI, fancybox v4 will support `<picture>` element and that will open new opportunities for developers (you can see preview of current progress here - http://fancyapps.com/next/)

Comment: Yes, I tried some things with the code above but so far I have no success...thats why I'm looking forward to v4 :-) When will it come out?

Comment: I am afraid I can not give any estimate, sorry.